# React function component not updating with new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have `React` function component `Input` it's a simple `input` field it takes only one `prop` named `epoch`, the value of `epoch` in milliseconds. inside the component, I use `moment` js to format this time to a `HH:mm` (hour:min) format, also I'm using `useState` inside the `Input` component to set `input` value while user updates the input I needed to check with complex algorithms and need to append +/- with number.

`Input.jsx`

```
import React, {useState, } from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'

function Input({epoch}){
  console.log(epoch)
  const translateValueToString = epochValue => {
    return moment(epochValue).format('HH:mm')
  }
  const [value, updateValue] = useState(translateValueToString(epoch))
  return <input value={value} onChange={(e) => {
    // i need to update the value with some complex calculation and update it
    updateValue(`${e.target.value}+2`)
  }}/>
}

export default Input
```

As you can see, I'm using the Internal state to update the value of the input, instead use directly use the prop, because I needed to join some string to the value while user types.

From parent Component, I'm sending `epoch` value as prop aslo in paren component I have button to update `epoch` value with +1 minute for each click.

`App.jsx`

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Input from './Input'
import moment from 'moment'

export default function App() {
  const [epoch, updateEpoch] = useState(moment().valueOf())
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Input epoch={epoch}/>
      <button onClick={() => {
        updateEpoch(epoch+60000)
      }}>ADD 1 min</button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect each click should update the input value with updated `epoch` prop value. But it wont happen. `useState` inside the Input won't fires.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-firefly-6ic78)

**Updated**

I cant use `useEffect` inside Input function it triggers multiple, multiple rerender, because im using `redux-form`.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
Please refer here - it should be `[value, setValue]` and not updateValue

Comment: Use `React.memo` to avoid re-render, use can use `useEffect` on changing of epoch value

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> const [value, updateValue] = useState(translateValueToString(epoch))
> ```

`translateValueToString` is used only once, to initialize state. Props change doesn't update `value`, `epoch` not used in rendering, no view update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateValue( translateValueToString(epoch) )
}, [epoch])
```